# Commentaries by Tantrika Acharyas on Mukhya Upanishads

Tags: upanishads, tantra, commentary

Did Any Acharya like Bhaskaracharya, Utapaladeva, Abhinavagupta etc. from Tantrika sect write their own commentary on [Mukhya Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukhya_Upanishads)? If yes, Please share the link to the book/text.

Answer (score 5):

In general, Tantrika gives practical implementation of the path most importance. And they don't tend to write commentaries on the texts of different school of thoughts.

However I could find only one commentary on Ishopanishad by Kaulacharya Satyananda available on archive.org:
[**Ishopanishad**](https://archive.org/details/isopanishadkaula)